# How to index and gsub a string within a dataframe using regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I am working on a text cleaning pipeline where I hope to apply a list of target words and corresponding replacement words within a dataframe to a given string (e.g., goats)
`goats <- c("goats like apples applesauce. goats like bananas bananasplits. goats like cheese cheesecake.")`

I am using a for loop to run down the list of targets and gsub with their corresponding replacements in the specified text (goats).  I want the substitution to only catch exact string matches (e.g., banana but not bananasplit). Here's the loop:

```
goatclean <- goats
for (i in seq_along(swap$target)) {
    goatclean <- gsub(swap$target[i], swap$replace[i], goatclean)
}
print(goatclean)
```

The output of this loop is:
"goats like mary maryauce. goats like linda lindaplits. goats like jane janecake."

I cannot figure out a way to gsub 'apples' from the dataframe when it is only an isolated word using regex -- I am getting errors when I add \s+ to:

```
gsub(\\s+(swap$target[i])\\s+, swap$replace[i], goatclean)
```

Any advice on how to get the output to the following:
"goats like mary applesauce. goats like linda bananasplits. goats like jane cheesecake."

Thanks everyone!

Comment: `gsub(sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b', swap$target[i]), swap$replace[i], goatclean)`. Although this seems to be a vectorization problem. There can be beter codes than a for loop. Probably if you include the swap dataset

Comment: To echo @Onyambu's comment, `stringr::str_replace_all` is vectorised over `string`, `pattern` and `replacement` so I would expect this to be possible in one line without the need for a loop.  And for large datasets, this should be *much* faster than looping.

Comment: I gave that a try: `maybe <- str_replace_all(goats, swap$target, swap$replace)` but no go. Output was: "goats like mary maryauce. goats like bananas bananasplits. goats like cheese cheesecake."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using word boundaries (`\\b`) around the pattern -

```
for (i in seq_along(swap$target)) {
  goatclean <- gsub(paste0('\\b', swap$target[i], '\\b'), swap$replace[i], goatclean)
}
```